# <Android>Force Close : WindowManager: Adding more than one toast window for UID at a time

Tags: android

Issue: Force Close because of Toast message

```
 W WindowManager: Adding more than one toast window for UID at a time.



    D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash

         E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.app.package, PID: 3181
         E AndroidRuntime: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add 
         window -- window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f7e2e66 has already been added
         E AndroidRuntime:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:707)
         E AndroidRuntime:  at 
         android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
         E AndroidRuntime:  at 
         android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
         E AndroidRuntime:  at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:459)
         E AndroidRuntime:  at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.handleMessage(Toast.java:342)
         E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

---

It seems issue is coming because of below change by Google
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/dc24f93

How we can get rid of this issue if I I want to keep all my Toast messages.

Comment: Hello Cliff: issue happens when we have Multiple toast associated with different functionality comes up one after the other

Comment: Thanks for the comments , it seems framework implementation is missing which has fixed this issue.  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/dc24f93